# still learning python and i cant figure out why im getting this as an error

Tags: python

```
print("Calculator!!!")
loop = 1
#title, obv
#basic inputs
numbercount = int(input("How many numbers are you doing math with? max is 3: "))


while loop == 1:
  if numbercount == 1:
    print("min characters are 2")
  elif numbercount == 2:
    mathtype = int(input("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplcation\n4. Division\n"))
  if mathtype == 1:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a + b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 2:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a - b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 3:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a * b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 4:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a / b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  else:
    print("try again")
  if numbercount == 3:
    mathtype = int(input("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplcation\n4. Division\n"))
  if mathtype == 1:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a + b + c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 2:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a - b - c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 3:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a * b * c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 4:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a / b / c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  else:
    print("try again")
else:
  print("Max Characters is 3")
```

> error message:
> Calculator!!!
> How many numbers are you doing math with? max is 3: 3
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 13, in 
> if mathtype == 1:
> NameError: name 'mathtype' is not defined

im still relatively new to python and i need some help :/ anything besides why are you using python or something would be helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think about the problem logically. Where the code says `if mathtype == 1:`, why should `mathtype` mean anything at all, yet? That would happen because of an *assignment*, like `mathtype = int(input("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplcation\n4. Division\n"))` - right? So. **Will that always happen first**? Why or why not? If it didn't happen, what do you think would be the result? Do you see how that corresponds to the error message?

Comment: Also: please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and **write much less code at a time**, and **make sure everything works** before moving on to the next part.

Comment: I forgot to put it in the main post but worked until I put it in a while loop

Comment: Don't try to put large blocks of existing code into new loops etc. Instead, learn to write functions, and try to keep them short and purposeful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined mathtype in an "elif" statement. That means if the if statement before it was true, then the code inside the elif statement won't run, which means that the integer mathtype will never be defined. To fix this, just put the first input inside another while loop, so it will continue to ask for the numbercount:

```
print("Calculator!!!")
loop = 1
#title, obv
#basic inputs


while loop == 1:
  while True:
    numbercount = int(input("How many numbers are you doing math with? max is 3: "))
    if numbercount == 1:
      print("min characters are 2")
    else:
      break
  mathtype = int(input("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplcation\n4. Division\n"))
  if mathtype == 1:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a + b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 2:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a - b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 3:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a * b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 4:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = a / b
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  else:
    print("try again")
  if numbercount == 3:
    mathtype = int(input("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplcation\n4. Division\n"))
  if mathtype == 1:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a + b + c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 2:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a - b - c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 3:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a * b * c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  elif mathtype == 4:
    print("format as\na = [number]\nb = [number]\nc = [number]\n\n")
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))
    d = a / b / c
    print("Your awnser is: ", c)
  else:
    print("try again")
else:
  print("Max Characters is 3")
```